# capture url in href tag

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I have an exit page that informs users that they are leaving my site. How do I capture the intended url from the referring page and send the user to it once they've acknowledged on the exit page that they're aware they're leaving my site and wish to continue to their destination? My current setup works with an absolute link but not with a relative path.

this works:

```
href="http://acme.com/company/brand/leaving/?url=http://www.about.info/choices/
```

this doesn't:

```
href="../COMPANY/BRAND/leaving/?url=http://www.about.info/choices/"
```

the continue button triggers the following function:

```
function gbye(){
    var url = window.location.toString();
    var url_arr=  url.split("?url=");   

if(url_arr.length>1)
{

    try
    { 
         window.location = url_arr[1]; 

    }
    catch (e)
    {
    }
}

    return false;
}
```

can anyone explain why the href with the relative path doesn't work (returns a directory list) and how I can make the relative path work?

Comment: You use capitals for the relative url, and normal character for the absolute url.

Comment: oops, thats a typo. I obscured the actual directory names for privacy's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most servers are running under a Linux environment, where the filesystem is case-sensitive, ie file names with different cases are treated different.

If the first link worked correctly, use `../company/brand/leaving/?url=...`. I recommend using a `/` (absolute root) instead of `../`, because you won't have to edit your files when you move the files to a different directory, when using `/`.

Comment: Bogus argument for rewriting the urls - if the site moves, then an absolute url will DEFINITELY have to be changed, while a relative url would only change if the parallel dir moves/renames.

Comment: @MarcB Consider `http://host.name/sub/dir/file.htm` to be a file, linking to `../dir/resource`. The file moves to `http://host.name/new.htm`. Now, assume the pointer to be `../../dir/resource`. At the first location, the link refers to `http://host.name/dir/resource`. At the new location, the file points to `http://host.name/dir/resource`. These two URLs are completely different. If `/` is used instead of `../`, this problem will never occur.

Comment: And if you change /sub to /newsub, then all the links have to rewritten anyways. Changing links from relative to abslute does not magically fix the problem. Either way, files have to be updated. Suggesting switchinh to absolute being a panacea is just outright false.

Comment: @MarcB Changing `sub` to `newsub` won't break the `/`-link, because the referred directory is at the root of the website. I've answered the question, and added a suggestion **related** to the question. Scroll up, and notice that the referred *directory tree* is located at the root of the website. `../` will only work in the subdirectories at the root, and won't work at `http://acme.com/first/second/`.

Comment: uh, yes it well. if the page has `<a href="/sub/page.html"`, and you rename `sub` to `newsub`, you've now got a broken link, because `/sub/page.html` will no longer exist. The same goes for a page in `/subdir/page.html` with `../sub/page.html`... if sub no longer exists, it won't magically re-link itself to newsub.